# Float precision issue - different values then from pgAdmin

Tags: java, postgresql, precision, jdbctemplate

I develop a Java project and running into a problem with incorrect text data value from the PostgreSQL database.

For example, in PostgreSQL I have a table with text type columns. Inside that table, I have a text value of 62.1 or something similar. When retrieving data with jdbcTemplate (query or queryForList method) the result is 62.09999999999999996.

When I use ResultSet getFloat (index) it works fine. But I need a different solution as my database is huge and the tables contain different values ​​on different column indexes. So if I get stuck with the getFloat (index) method then I will have to implement a different approach for each table.

Code Example.
Database pocedure:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.float_test_ret_cast_table2(
    )
    RETURNS TABLE(value text, value2 character varying, value3 text, value4 text, value5 text, value6 text) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_float_cast_test2;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE tmp_float_cast_test2 AS ( 
            SELECT value, value2, value3::text, value4::text, value5::text, (value6::real / 100)::text FROM "FloatTest"    
        )';
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tmp_float_cast_test2;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Query results:

- from pg admin:

```
select * from float_test_ret_cast_table2()
62.1 | 62,1 | 62.1111 | 62.1111 | 62.1111 | 6.21
```

from java:

```
select * from float_test_ret_cast_table2()
62.1 | 62,1 | 62.1111000000000004 | 62.1110992 | 62.1111 | 6.20999999999999996
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If it is a float, you use `getFloat()`, I dont undertand what you need exactly.  Perhaps show code, where your problem in the code.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `text` column? That is a really bad idea to begin with. Additionally: `float` (and `double precision`)  are **approximate** data types. What you store is not necessarily the same that you get back. If you need accurate numbers, use `numeric`

Comment: It is too big project for me to handle every query and implement getFloat() everywhere it is needed.
I am not storing numbers in text type columns. To be more specific. When I call the procedure which returns table with text type columns in pgAdmin I get exact values. As I wrote above, for example 23.9. Unfortunately from java it returns 23.899995.

Comment: Well, `float` (and `double precision`)  is a _approximate_ data type (see https://floating-point-gui.de/). You don't always get back what you put in. When you need exact values, use `numeric`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and support :) All problem was about 'extra_float_digits' database variable. A driver which java use in my project use 'extra_float_digits' =3, wheras postgresql has value 0. So on every database connection I need to set 'extra_float_digits' =0. So on every database connection I need to set 'extra_float_digits' =0. This resolve problem and avoid doing changes on every sql query results. Hope that this topic will help save some time to anyone else.